# Automate User-Defined Function to Process Dataframes

Tags: r

I'd like to create a code that takes a varying number of dataframes `X1, X2, X3...XN` containing four columns of data `time, height, start, group` and automatically runs them through a user-defined function `HL_plot` from `Vulntookit`. I'm guessing I could use a for loop, but am still very new to R and a little stuck on this step. If I use the function manually, the code looks like this:

```
HL.plot (level = X1[, 2], time = X1[, 1], period = 0.3, 
         phantom = TRUE, tides = "H")
HL.plot (level = X2[, 2], time = X2[, 1], period = 0.3, 
         phantom = TRUE, tides = "H")
HL.plot (level = X3[, 2], time = X3[, 1], period = 0.3, 
         phantom = TRUE, tides = "H")
HL.plot (level = XN[, 2], time = XN[, 1], period = 0.3, 
         phantom = TRUE, tides = "H")
```

The function plots the second `height` and first `time` columns of data.

Comment: how about using `Xnew <- rbind(X1, X2, X3,.. XN)`? this will makes sure all the Dataframes concatenate into one by row-wise, so you can use the function straight into `Xnew`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I'm still struggling with the specific code used to assign ```Xnew``` to an unknown or changing amount of dataframes ```X1, X2, X3, X4......```

Comment: what kind of struggling you experiences? are there any error executing it? try to just enter an available dataframe into it..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that if you have a lots of dataframes that named as follows `X1, X2, X3,..X100,..XN` the best way I can think to automatically concatenate it (rather than typing 1 by 1 dataframe into `rbind()` parameter, is to create an evaluate expression by string:

```
eval_expression = "Xnew <- rbind("
#example if n is 200 (200 dataframes available)
n <- 200
for(a in 1:n){
  if(a == n){
    eval_expression <- paste0(eval_expression, "X",a,")")
  }
  else{
    eval_expression <- paste0(eval_expression, "X",a,",")
  }
}
```

you can also try look what is inside `eval_expression` after executing above codes, and then finally do the final execution:

```
eval(parse(text = eval_expression))
```